# Passar ponteiro como paramêtro de função C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, funções

Bom dia pessoal, tenho o seguinte problema:
tenho uma classe que representa uma Lista, e a partir dela criei três objetos(não sei qual npme se dá) lista1(5), lista2(5), lista3(10).

```
    template<class T>class Lista{
        private:
            T *itens;
            int ultimo, maxTam;

        public:
            Lista(int maxTam);
                    void insere(T item);
    };

    template <class T> Lista<T>::Lista(int maxTam){
        this->maxTam = maxTam;
        this->itens = new T[maxTam];
        this->ultimo = 0;
    }

    template <class T> void Lista<T>::insere(T item){
        if(ultimo == maxTam){
            cout<< "Lista Cheia!"<<endl;
        }else{
            this->itens[this->ultimo] = item;
            this->ultimo++;
        }
    }

int main(){
    Lista<int> lista1(5); //esta lista ja está cheia
    Lista<int> lista2(5); //esta lista já está cheia
    Lista<int> lista3(10); //esta lista deve receber o conteudo das duas listas anteriores intercalados.
    return 0;
}
```

suponde que eu ja enchi as duas primeiras listas, como copiar os itens delas para a fila3, passando-as como parametro de uma função? Fiz a função a baixo, mas não funciona.

```
    //Aqui o protótipo do método.
    template<class T> T Lista<T>::MisturaListas(Lista<T> *l1, Lista<T> *l2, Lista<T> *l3){

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            l3->insere(l1[i]);
            l3->insere(l2[i]);


        }
   }


//Aqui a parte que fica na classe
T MisturaListas(Lista<T> *l1, Lista<T> *l2, Lista<T> *l3);

//Aqui o main
int main(){
        Lista<int> lista1(5); //esta lista ja está cheia
        Lista<int> lista2(5); //esta lista já está cheia
        Lista<int> lista3(10); //esta lista deve receber o conteudo das duas listas anteriores intercalados.
        lista3.MisturaListas<int>(lista1, lista2, lista3);
        return 0;
    }
```

Espero que tenha entendido, se poderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas alguns ajustes no código fonte da pergunta já produziram o resultado, veja:

Novo método get():

```
T get(int i);
```

Esse método é necessário para obter itens que foram adicionados na lista, pois a classe Lista encapsula um array, que por sua vez não é acessível do modo convencional utilizando `[]`.

Assinatura do método MisturaListas():

```
T MisturaListas(Lista<T> l1, Lista<T> l2, Lista<T> l3);
```

Esse método não poderia receber ponteiros para Lista.

Correção no loop do método MisturaListas():

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    l3.insere(l1.get(i));
    l3.insere(l2.get(i));
}
```

Como foi citado, o métoto `get()` foi criado para acessar itens inseridos na lista.

Ao final o novo código fonte fica assim (veja rodando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/3MMQ2d))

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>class Lista{
    private:
        T *itens;
        int ultimo, maxTam;

    public:
        Lista(int maxTam);
        void insere(T item);
        T get(int i);
        T MisturaListas(Lista<T> l1, Lista<T> l2, Lista<T> l3);

};

template <class T> Lista<T>::Lista(int maxTam){
    this->maxTam = maxTam;
    this->itens  = new T[maxTam];
    this->ultimo = 0;
}

template <class T> void Lista<T>::insere(T item){
    if(ultimo == maxTam){
       cout<< "Lista Cheia!"<<endl;
    }else{
        this->itens[this->ultimo] = item;
        this->ultimo++;
    }
}

template<class T> T Lista<T>::get(int i){
    return itens[i];
}

//Aqui o protótipo do método.
template<class T> T Lista<T>::MisturaListas(Lista<T> l1, Lista<T> l2, Lista<T> l3){

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        l3.insere(l1.get(i));
        l3.insere(l2.get(i));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Lista<int> lista1(5); //esta lista ja está cheia
    lista1.insere(0);
    lista1.insere(1);
    lista1.insere(2);
    lista1.insere(3);
    lista1.insere(4);
    for(int _i = 0; _i < 5; _i++){
        cout<<lista1.get(_i);
    }

    cout<<endl;
    Lista<int> lista2(5); //esta lista já está cheia
    lista2.insere(5);
    lista2.insere(6);
    lista2.insere(7);
    lista2.insere(8);
    lista2.insere(9);
    for(int _i = 0; _i < 5; _i++){
        cout<<lista2.get(_i);
    }

    Lista<int> lista3(10); //esta lista deve receber o conteudo das duas listas anteriores intercalados.
    lista3.MisturaListas(lista1, lista2, lista3);

    cout<<endl;

    for(int _i = 0; _i < 10; _i++){
        cout<<lista3.get(_i);
    }
    cout << endl << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No restante, tudo está ok.

Comment: Fabio só não entendi como funciona esse método get(), pois fiz um metodo imprime() pra imprimir as tres listas, ele imprimiu as duas primeiras e retornou que a lista3 está vazia :S.

Comment: O método `get()` tem como objetivo obter um determinado item da lista e com ele você expõe a capacidade de manipular a lista por quem for utilizá-la. É assim porque quem utiliza uma instância de `Lista` não sabe que dentro dessa classe existe um array. Desse modo você promove dois itens importantes em POO: baixo acoplamento e alta coesão.